# Where is the PivotViewer collections excel addin gone and many other resources?

Tags: microsoft-excel, plugins

I am trying to get something working with the Silverlight PivotViewer control, and I am having a hard time getting any of the referenced resources (on the web). Most of the links are broken or gone. Some examples:

- http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/pivotviewer/ (try out Documentation)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91552/Working-With-Silverlight-PivotViewer

And generaly a website which was previously getpivot.com is now gone (pointing to bing.com).
I would be mostly interested in the excel plugin that once existed but also in all other related resources.

Comment: Yes, i am also looking for the excel addon, all traces of this file are gone!... http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/pivot-viewer/excel-tool

Answer (score 1):

Check this article [here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2012/09/01/Semantic-Zoom.aspx?Page=1)
Creating a PivotViewer Application
Because the PivotViewer is now a part of the Silverlight SDK, the only required installations are Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and the Microsoft Silverlight 5 Tools for Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

Once you have everything installed, create a Silverlight 5 application by selecting File, New and Project from the Visual Studio menu. After the New Project dialog is displayed, select a Silverlight Application

for any code ressources check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.pivot.pivotviewer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I enjoyed the excel pivot collection tool because i could easily generate thousands of records for illustrative purposes. I am specifically looking for this tool.. agreed you can create the content via code. but i find it strange that this tool just disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Like others, I have been scouring the Net for the Excel add-in, with absolutely no luck. The closest thing I've found is a web site - createpivot.com - that provides a tool to create static collections. I know so little about the technology that I can't evaluate its functionality. But it's worth a look, I'd say.

Comment: yes, this may work!... i will give it a shot.. still its strange that the excel addon has disappeared, since i know it was even running on excel 2010.

Answer (score -1):

Found a person with a backup of the tool. you can find a link to their dropbox account from [this forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/4ed06b45-dde4-4388-b1d9-30456429ed0a/pivotviewer-excel-addin)

Hope you come right.